# parsing list string vector to multiple column data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to convert data of form:

```
dt <- data.table(foo = c(c('a=a1|b=b1'),c('a=a2|b=b2|c=c2'),c('a=a3|d=d3')))
```

to form:

```
data.table(a=c('a1','a2','a3'),b=c('b1','b2',NA),c=c(NA,'c2',NA),d=c(NA,NA,'d3'))
```

I tried to parse first step using:

```
lapply(dt$foo, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = '|', fixed = T)))
```

but couldn't proceed further. Any pointers?

Comment: Why couldn't you proceed further? What went wrong?

Comment: using `do.call(rbind, lapply(dt$foo, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = '|', fixed = T))))` imputes and result in weird result and using lapply is getting too nested

Comment: are there actually character vectors inside `foo` or are they all length one? i.e. is `dt$foo` class `chr` or `list`? At the moment you have put length one vectors in it which are the same as scalars in R

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(dt[, row := .I], "foo", "|", "long")[, cSplit(.SD, "foo", "=")][, dcast(.SD, row ~ foo_1, value.var = "foo_2")]` should do it.

Comment: class is character. Data is about different plugins present in different system so could potentially have different length. Also sometime plugin absense in denoted by 'f'.

Comment: can you provide a sample of data that includes those cases then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `read.table` function to read values as `key-value` pair and then finally convert into data.frame. The `dplyr::bind_rows` can help to join different rows.

```
dt <- data.table(foo = c(c('a=a1|b=b1'),c('a=a2|b=b2|c=c2'),c('a=a3|d=d3')))

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mapply(function(x){
  t <- read.table(text = gsub("\\|","\n",x), sep=c("="), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  t <- as.data.frame(t(t), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(t) <- t[1,]
  t <- t[-1,]
  }, dt$foo))
#    a    b    c    d
# 1 a1   b1 <NA> <NA>
# 2 a2   b2   c2 <NA>
# 3 a3 <NA> <NA>   d3
```

**UPDATED:** `data.table` based solution as suggested by @abhiieor will be as:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mapply(function(x){
  t <- read.table(text = gsub("\\|","\n",x), sep=c("="), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  t <- as.data.frame(t(t), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(t) <- t[1,]
  t <- t[-1,]
  }, dt$foo), use.names = T, fill = T)
```

Comment: data.table equivalent will be: `rbindlist(mapply(function(x){
+   t <- read.table(text = gsub("\\|","\n",x), sep=c("="), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
+   t <- as.data.frame(t(t), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+   colnames(t) <- t[1,]
+   t <- t[-1,]
+   }, dt$foo), use.names = T, fill = T)`

Comment: Very correct. I will modify and your comments in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is most close using pure data.table and base R functions. Though I upvoted all solutions.

Comment: @abhiieor That's great spirit. I appreciate and upvote questions with relevant  code to create reproducible data.

Answer (score 4):

Will update if more cases are provided. This is not a `data.table` because I don't use it, but afaik it should still work? Maybe if coerced to `data.frame` first.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- tibble(foo = c(c('a=a1|b=b1'),c('a=a2|b=b2|c=c2'),c('a=a3|d=d3')))
tibble(a=c('a1','a2','a3'),b=c('b1','b2',NA),c=c(NA,'c2',NA),d=c(NA,NA,'d3'))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   a     b     c     d    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a1    b1    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 a2    b2    c2    <NA> 
#> 3 a3    <NA>  <NA>  d3

dt %>%
  mutate(foo = str_split(foo, pattern = "\\|")) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  unnest() %>%
  separate(foo, into = c("col", "val"), sep = "=") %>%
  spread(col, val)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   rowid a     b     c     d    
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 a1    b1    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2     2 a2    b2    c2    <NA> 
#> 3     3 a3    <NA>  <NA>  d3
```

Created on 2018-04-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comment to an answer, you can try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dt[, row := .I], "foo", "|", "long")[
  , cSplit(.SD, "foo", "=")][
    , dcast(.SD, row ~ foo_1, value.var = "foo_2")]
#    row  a    b    c    d
# 1:   1 a1   b1 <NA> <NA>
# 2:   2 a2   b2   c2 <NA>
# 3:   3 a3 <NA> <NA>   d3
```

You can, of course, also just use a combination of `strsplit`, `tstrsplit`, and `dcast` as well.

```
dt[, unlist(strsplit(foo, "|", TRUE)), 1:nrow(dt)][
  , c("col", "val") := tstrsplit(V1, "=", fixed = TRUE)][
    , dcast(.SD, nrow ~ col, value.var = "val")]
#    nrow  a    b    c    d
# 1:    1 a1   b1 <NA> <NA>
# 2:    2 a2   b2   c2 <NA>
# 3:    3 a3 <NA> <NA>   d3
```